# How to resolve invalid signal "media-configure" in gstreamer when used along with GTK+3 source

Tags: 64-bit, gstreamer, gtk3, gobject

I am using Gstreamer to create a video streaming server along with GTK+3 for GUI. I followed below procedure to setup the source code in Windows 64bit :

- GTK+3 is installed using vcpkg
- Gstreamer (ver 1.16) is installed using the oficial gstreamer downloads
- Gstreamer libraries are pointed in the environment variables using GST_PLUGIN_PATH
- The source code is setup in visual studio 2019

I am facing issue in g_signal_connect used in gstreamer source code

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(app->factory), "media-configure", (GCallback)media_config, app);
```

with the below warning.

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: C:\vcpkg\buildtrees\glib\src\2.52.3-34a15219ec\gobject\gsignal.c:2523: signal 'media-configure' is invalid for instance '0000026441B40280' of type '(NULL)'
```

Since both GTK+3 and Gstreamer uses gObject for signal_connect, at runtime the gstreamer refer to gsignal.c of gtk. When I run the gstreamer source separately without using GTK runtime libraries, I am able to get the output.

If I remove the gobject reference of gtk and link the gstreamer library, then GTK signal connects are not working.

How can I fix the GObject reference issue ?